# MySQL filter results from a SubSelect using AND or HAVING

Tags: mysql

I have a query that looks basically like this:

```
Select t.id, 
       (
       Select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', td.id) SEPARATOR ',') as list
       From Table t2
       ) as id_list // this will add a comma delimited list
From Table t1
Where t1.status IS NULL
And id_list IN (3)
```

The query result is like this...

```
id|id_list
-------------------- 
1 |1
9 |1,3,12,10,15
```

This does not work as MySQL will not allow me to filter by id_list as an And conditional...

I have also tried this in place of the And conditional, but it does not work also...

```
Having id_list IN (3)
```

How can I filter these results based upon the id_list matching some parameter which I set, in this case 3.

I just want to return record id 9, not 1.

Thanks

Comment: `id_list` is a comma separated list of all the ids of your table. How can it be equal to 3? You have to explain your requirement and better post sample data and expected results.

Comment: It is not equal to 3, that's why i use IN "id_list IN (3)" ... It's clearly explained. Nowhere in my code did I ever say that id_list = 3.

Comment: `id_list IN (3)` is equivalent to `id_list = 3`

Comment: No, that is incorrect. I could do a query in MySQL and say id IN (1, 3, 4, 5) and it would pull back records 1, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: This is why I am asking, can I perform this task using IN and saying that 3 exists as a value in the list? If NOT then, how can it be accomplished

Comment: And if you do a query and say `id IN (3)` it is the same as `id = 3`

Comment: Okay, great then how is it done? My code is clearly explained what I am looking to accomplish and rather than hash out over whether id = 3 how do I accomplish what is desired?

Comment: Your code does not work. Even after correcting the syntactical errors this code can't return the results that you say that it returns. Also your requirement is **not** clearly explained.

Comment: You are flagged.

Comment: I will provide help to those who want to learn. Even if you got the solution you wanted still you did not learn anything. Read my comments again as a last attempt to learn something. At least you edited your comment after the flag.

Comment: I have no desire to learn from you :) #theEnd

Comment: *I have no desire to learn* should be enough and accurate.

Comment: Nope, just from you. See the answers below? Yeah, you didn't provide any solutions - just complaints. My code works awesome now, no thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for a value `'3'` in a comma separated list e.g.  `'2,3,5'` we can use MySQL  `FIND_IN_SET` function.

As a demonstration:

`SELECT FIND_IN_SET('3','2,3,5')` returns 2

`SELECT FIND_IN_SET('3','7,11')`  returns 0

---

So for the query in the question, given `id_list` is a comma separated list, we could do

```
 HAVING FIND_IN_SET('3',id_list)
```

or equivalently

```
 HAVING FIND_IN_SET('3',id_list) > 0
```

---

Note that the `IN` comparison operator does not work like the `FIND_IN_SET` function.

The `IN` is equivalent to equality comparison of individual values. For example,

```
SELECT 3 IN (2,3,5)
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT 3 = 2 OR 3 = 3 OR 3 = 5
```

As another example:

```
SELECT 3 IN ('2,3,5')
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT 3 = '2,3,5'
```

Comment: I think since `GROUP BY` happens in sub query we should not use `HAVING` for outer query.

Comment: @Alex:  I'm certain that `id_list` alias can be referenced in the `HAVING` clause. I'm not sure that `id_list` alias from the SELECT list is available to the `WHERE` clause; actually, I'm pretty sure its not valid to reference `id_list` in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:

```
SELECT t.id, 
       (
       SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', td.id) SEPARATOR ',') as list
       FROM Table t2
       ) as id_list 
FROM Table t1
WHERE t1.status IS NULL
AND FIND_IN_SET(3, id_list) > 0
```